# Parameter 0 of constructor in TestController required a bean of type TestProvider that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, conditional-statements

So basically I'm getting the error.

`Parameter 0 of constructor in TestController required a bean of type TestProvider that could not be found.`

However the TestController class is annotated with `@ConditionalOnBean(TestProvider.class)`. Even better, this only happens when run in a Docker container. When running from IntelliJ, everything works as I would expect. What am I doing wrong?

Why is spring insisting on creating my controller class, when I explicitly told it not to?

Spring Boot 2.7.2 if it matters.

Comment: What's the point in a `@DependsOnBean` annotation if your `TestController` explicitly uses `TestProvider` in its constructor? How did you tell Spring not to create the controller class? Without seeing the relevant code it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: From what I understand @DependsOnBeran prevents creation if the given Bean does not exist. It's worked that way for 4 years, and like I said it works great from IntelliJ, it just doesn't work in Docker for some reason. It's this project: https://github.com/actoaps/fafnir-sso

Comment: Sorry, @ConditionalOnBean. I will edit.

Comment: `it just doesn't work in Docker for some reason` - the reason is described in [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnBean.html): `The condition can only match the bean definitions that have been processed by the application context so far and, as such, it is strongly recommended to use this condition on auto-configuration classes only`

Comment: Yeah. That doesn't really explain it tho', at least not in a way that makes sense (to me).

It goes to look for a Bean, it discovers one doesn't exist, and somehow that satisfies the conditional, and it goes on to create the controller anyway?

Is there some other way to prevent a (Controller) bean from being created if a (dependency) bean does not currently exist in the IoC context?